# Property 'address' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hey I'm passing object from one page to another & trying to store in object in another page but facing an error during that. Es Lint error.

```
 accountData:any={
    name:this.tenantAccount.name,
    telephone_number:this.tenantAccount.telephone_number,
    mobile_number:this.tenantAccount.owner.mobile_number,
    address:this.tenantAccount.address.address,
    owner_name:this.tenantAccount.owner.name,
    tenant_email:this.tenantAccount.tenant_email,
    created_by:this.tenantAccount.created_by.name,
    source_name:this.tenantAccount.source.name,
    latitude:this.tenantAccount.address.latitude,
    longitude:this.tenantAccount.address.longitude,
    state:this.tenantAccount.address.state.name
  }
```

The Above One the code to Store. It's Because Of Typescript

Why it's happening & what is the best possible solution

Comment: Can you post `tenantAccount` variable declaration?

Comment: Most likely it should be `address:this.tenantAccount.address`, not `.address.address`

Answer (score 0):

As per the error `Property 'address' does not exist on type 'string'`, `this.tenantAccount.address` is of string type but as per your code you are considering it as an object and trying to access the `address` property from it which is not correct as per the error.

I think it should be `this.tenantAccount.address ✅` instead of `this.tenantAccount.address.address ❌`